# Cannot understand `TypeError` in function call

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a function that takes a parameter that is a list of 4-element lists that represent approval ballots for a single riding; the order of the inner list elements corresponds to the order of the parties in a list of parties called `PARTY_INDICES`.

The party with the most number of 'yes' votes wins.

It should return a 2-tuple where the first element is the name of the winning party and the second element is a four-element list that contains the number of yes votes for each party. The order of the list elements corresponds to the order of the parties in `PARTY_INDICES`.

This is what I have so far:

```
def voting_approval(approval):
    ''' (list of list of str) -> tuple of (str, list of int)
        In Approval Voting, the party that receives the most YES votes wins the seat.
    '''

    parties=['NDP','GREEN','LIBERAL','CPC']
    totals = [sum('YES') for x in zip(*approval)]
    win_party = parties[totals.index(max(totals))]
    return (win_party, totals)
```

However, when I try `voting_approval(['YES','NO','YES','NO'],['YES','NO','YES','YES'],['YES','YES','YES','YES'])`.

I get the following error:

```
builtins.TypeError: voting_approval() takes exactly 1 positional argument (3 given)
```

Comment: That's because you're passing it three arguments (three different lists) and it only expects one.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - in order to avoid downvotes, please take the time to format your question.  I have edited yours to clean it up.

Comment: thank you! its my first time

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to troubleshoot your function the reason for your error is that you are passing 3 lists as arguments to the function when it only takes a single parameter.

A different way you could approach the function would be:

```
def vote(arg):
    parties = ['NDP','GREEN','LIBERAL','CPC']
    values = [0,0,0,0]
    for lis in arg:
        for no, item in enumerate(lis):
            if item == 'Yes':
                values[no] += 1

    return (parties[values.index(max(values))], max(values))
```

Then use it like:

```
vote([['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'],['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']])
```

This returns ('LIBERAL', 2)

Comment: Could you give me an idea in how to fix that? Im not very good

Comment: What happens when you try - voting_approval(['YES','NO','YES','NO'])

Comment: builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: That is because you're trying to sum('Yes') as 'Yes' is a string and sum is used to add integers.

Comment: well.. i cant do totals = [(sum(int(('YES')))) for x in zip(*approval)]... hmmm

Comment: do i have to use a for loop in approval, and use count method to find all the "YES'?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a rough function that should do what you're after.

Comment: can you explain what the "for no," and enumerate is? please

Comment: Enumerating a list will provide two values, the position (no in my example) and the value (item in my example). So each time it iterates through the list it will return two values so I provide the two variables to store them. Eg/ for the first run through on my example no = 0 and item = 'Yes', the second time through no = 1 and item = 'No' and so on.

For a much more complete explanation I suggest you check out the docs on enumerate - http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

I'll solve what seems to be your main problem, counting the number of 'yes' votes.

```
party_list = ['foo','bar','zoo']
yes_votes = {}
sample_votes = [['no','yes','no'],['yes','yes','no'],['no','no','no']]

for inner_list in sample_votes:
   for party_index, vote in enumerate(inner_list):
      if vote.lower() == 'yes':
          if party_list[party_index] not in yes_votes:
              yes_votes[party_list[party_index]] = 1
          else:
              yes_votes[party_list[party_index]] += 1

print 'Winner is ',max(yes_votes, key=lambda x: yes_votes[x])
```

Comment: thanks alot but the problem is i want to solve this without using any imports! :(

Comment: is there anyway you could solve this in a simpler way? i didnt learn key=lambda or enumerate yet..

Comment: This is one of the simplest ways to do it :)

Comment: @user1864828: `collections.defaultdict` is actually part of the Python standard library, so you don't need to install anything (if that's the base of what you wanted to stay away from).

Comment: damn.. Could you post the solution directly to my problem ? maybe that way i can understand easier..

Comment: @kuyan I think this is a homework assignment and they aren't allowed to use standard libraries but do it the "long" way.

Comment: What's the problem? Two people have given you answers, and since this is obviously homework; don't expect people to do your assignments for you; else how do you expect to learn anything?

Comment: can you explain what enumerate is